# images not appearing on page after ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

I wonder if you can help me out once again...

I am making a call to a php page using ajax to pass the clientwidth value to it so that I can size the images appropriately. Where I am making the ajax call from is within a "main" div of the calling page, but the images are not being displayed. Can you help?

My ajax call:

```
 <script>
     // Get the HTTP Object
function getHTTPObject(){
   if (window.ActiveXObject) 
       return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) 
       return new XMLHttpRequest();
   else {
      alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
      return null;
   }
}
w=document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    // Implement business logic    
    httpObject = getHTTPObject();
    if (httpObject != null) {
        httpObject.open("GET", "imagedisplay.php?width=" + w + "&id=" + <?php print $row['id'] ?> +"&imageno="+<?php print $imageno ?>, true);
        httpObject.send(null);

    }
var httpObject = null;
</script>
```

...and the associated php file...

```
<?php
 include "connection.php";
    $id=$_GET["id"];
    $w=$_GET["width"];
    $imageno=$_GET["imageno"];
    $query = "Select * from courses where id = '$id'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysqli_error($connection));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {        
    $table="<table><tr>";
        switch ($imageno) {
        case 1:
        $photowidth=$w;
        break;
        case 2:
        $photowidth=$w/2;
        break;
        case 3:
        $photowidth=$w/3;
        break;
        case 4:
        $photowidth=$w/2;
        break;
        case 5:
        $photowidth=$w/3;
        break;
        case 6:
        $photowidth=$w/3;
        break;
    }
    if ($row['iamge1']!=NULL) {
        $table .="<td><img src=\"../".$row['image1']."\" width=\"".$photowidth."\" border=\"0\"></td>";
        }
        if ($row['image2']!=NULL) {
        $table .="<td><img src=\"../".$row['image2']."\" width=\"".$photowidth."\" border=\"0\"></td>";
    }
        if ($row['image3']!=NULL) {
        $table .="<td><img src=\"../".$row['image3']."\" width=\"".$photowidth."\" border=\"0\"></td>";
        }
        if ($row['image4']!=NULL) {
        $table .="<td><img src=\"../".$row['image4']."\" width=\"".$photowidth."\" border=\"0\"></td>";
        }
        if ($row['image5']!=NULL) {
        $table .="<td><img src=\"../".$row['image5']."\" width=\"".$photowidth."\" border=\"0\"></td>";
        }
        if ($row['image6']!=NULL) {
        $table .="<td><img src=\"../".$row['image6']."\" width=\"".$photowidth."\" border=\"0\"></td>"; 
        }
    }
    $table.="</tr><table>";
    print $table;
    ?>
```

I know the php page is being called because when I introduced some errors into it, it was reported in the apache logs. I have also manually fed the key/value pairs into the file and the images then appear on the page. ta beforehand...

Comment: you aren't doing anything with the response from the ajax call. You send the request to the server, but there's no code which processes the response. Have you studied a basic AJAX tutorial? It would generally show you how to do that. Also, this code appears to get executed the moment the script is loaded into your page. In that case, what's the point of generating an ajax call? Surely you could just draw the `img` tags directly onto the page using a PHP function (you could wrap the contents of imagedisplay.php into a function and just call that directly from your page and echo the result).

Comment: Another thing I feel obliged to mention (although it's not the cause of your problem): Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: P.S. Most of this seems unnecessary anyway, you can simply use CSS to size the images responsively, if you're worried about the width of the page. Maybe you should research that instead.

Comment: relative links in the url are never a good idea. check your network panel for requests, if they have 404 code, then your paths are wrong!

Comment: @delboy1978uk relative paths in the URL are always a good idea, it makes the code portable. If you hard code the whole URL you have to change the code whenever you deploy to a new server (e.g. dev to test to live). Do you really mean "paths relative to the current page" vs "paths relative to the application's root"?

Comment: No one said anything about hard coding the domain? If a sites root is in a public folder, which contains img, css, js folders, then all image links should be `/img/rest/of/path/to/some.jpg`. The browser knows it's on whatever domain. Having a relative link dropping out of folders with `../` can lead to 404's everywhere.

Comment: @delboy1978uk you forgot to tag me, but I saw it anyway. Doing it the way you've suggested can also lead to 404s everywhere...it depends where the application gets deployed. If it's in a subfolder of the main domain (e.g. `http://www.example.com/application/` so that the "img" folder is `http://www.example.com/application/img`) then your method will also fail. The best guidance is to do whatever suits the circumstance.

Comment: @delboy1978uk In any case, the question contains no direct evidence that the URL is at fault. Can I suggest that it's probably better to ask for clarification about what the exact problem or error actually is. Instead of suggesting an error and getting them to look for it specifically, simply ask whether there are any errors, or not. Then you don't unintentionally lead the OP down a pointless diversionary rabbit hole. What _is_ clear from the code is that, as I mentioned above, the response from the ajax is ignored. So even if the URL is wrong, once corrected, it still won't work.

Comment: @ADyson. How would I go about wrapping what is in imagedisplay.php in a separate function. I thought the whole point of ajax was to pass variable values from javascript to php, so how would I get the clientwidth; there is no equivalent in php. You say there is also a way to do it in css. I can only see the width value being any use. could you direct me, if I'm wrong. ta beforehand

Comment: @ADyson. I think I've figured it out. Basically set 3 image classes in css then instead of the ajax script, write javascript to get the imageno value, and dependent on that  concatenate the string (along with the appropriate print values in php) with the appropriate image class. Thanks!

Comment: you shouldn't need to write any code to set the width. CSS will let you use percentages or other proportionate values so you don't have to set an absolute size, and you can set the width of the element(s) in which the images are contained to make sure it fits the screen size as well. Maybe take a tutorial on Responsive Design.